# How do I find a value on the x-axis in the y-axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have asimple code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = [0.85,0.50,0.27,0.15,0.10,0.05,0.03,0]
x = [0,50,100,150,200,280,300,400]
plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
plt.plot(x, y)
```

I want to learn the value of x (example: 139) in y from the graph.

Comment: Do you mean find `x` given `y`? i.e., given y = 0.50, find x (which is 50).

Comment: No i want to learn value of y. Example : x=50 and find y ?(0.50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d)

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
y = [0.85,0.50,0.27,0.15,0.10,0.05,0.03,0]
x = [0,50,100,150,200,280,300,400]
print(interp1d(x, y)(139)) # prints 0.1764
```